# Are there any supersonic aircraft with strictly mechanical controls?

Tags: flight-controls, supersonic

Are there or is it possible at all to create a supersonic aircraft with strictly mechanical (human powered without boosters) controls?

I know there was an attempt: Bede BD-10 but it never reached supersonic speed.

Have there been successful planes/designs that implemented it?

Comment: Interesting question! Welcome to av.se!

Comment: @mins yes I mean no amplification like pneumatic, electric or hydraulic - just sheer muscle power.

Comment: There are two kind of hydraulics, with and without power assistance. For instance, hydraulic bicycle brake merely transmit human power, just like a lever and without power boost.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's one I can think of immediately, and that's the granddaddy of them all, the [X-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_X-1). The X-1's control system was unassisted and it had no hydraulic system. The only part of the control system that was assisted was the horizontal stabilizer, which was [operated using high-pressure nitrogen gas](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/history/HistoricAircraft/X-1/techdata.html).

I think most of the early supersonic test airplanes were mechanically operated .

Comment: Yes I thought of X-1 but it was a very marginal case...

Comment: You asked for a successful design @Artyom, I'd say breaking the sound barrier qualifies.